# In WPF, is there a way to bind properties without requiring a backing field?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In the example below, the backing field is not performing any type of calculation and is simply just returning a value. Is there a way to write this without requiring a backing field? I'm not really seeing the purpose of having one in this instance. If my XAML is binding directly to Age, I don't really know why I also need _age.

```
private int _age;
public int Age
{
    get {return _age; }
    set
    {
        _age = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Age");
    }
}

private void ButtonClickIncrease(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Age++;
}
private void ButtonClickDecrease(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Age--;
}
```

Comment: You should really use MVVM pattern. In your ViewModel you can autoimplement INPC with Fody.PropertyChanged

Comment: @SirRufo Yup. Who doesn't love undebuggable, untestable, unpredictable code and using some random 3rd party library that randomly injects random opcodes into your code? Not to mention one that uses a bunch of slow reflection to do it? I'll agree on the MVVM comment though :).

Comment: I am using MVVM and INPC. I thought that would have been implied by showing OnPropertyChanged in the setter. I still don't quite understand why I need the backing field though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the backing field is not performing any calculation, it is used to store the value of the `Age` property. You need it in order to return the value in the getter and to assign the new value in the setter. If you didn't have it, what would the getter return? What would the setter store?

Perhaps you're used to automatic properties, where you don't seem to use a backing field. Automatic properties are a shorthand when your getter and setter do nothing else but return and assign the property. However, because you're doing something else (that is, `OnPropertyChanged("Age")`), you can't use an automatic property and must therefore hand-code the getter and setter using a backing field. See [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties).

Comment: Thank you for explanation. You're right in that I'm used to using automatic properties so I was assuming that the value of Age was just stored within Age itself. But now it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: You could just have an automatic property. You would need to raise property changed whenever you set it though. Assuming you need to see the value change in the ui. It's not always necessary to see ui respond immediately to a property change.